# How to append the a contents in a file into another file before }

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, copy

I have 2 files.
File 1: source.sh
File 2: destination.sh

I want to insert the contents of File 1 into File 2. But i don't want to insert the contents at the end of the file. 
The last line of File 2 is **"}"**

**I want to insert the content of File 1 into File 2 before "}"**

Below is my code:

```
filename50 - /path/of/the/file #source
my_file4 - /path/of/the/file   #destination
cat "$my_file4" >> "$filename50"
```

The above code insert the code at the end of the file...Can anyone please help me to insert the contents in the destination file before **}**
Any help is appreciated.

**Sample code:**

**Source.sh**

```
a
b
c
```

**Destination.sh**

```
{
w
e
r
t
y
}
```

**Output expected:**

```
{
w
e
r
t
y
a
b
c
}
```

The contents in the source.sh should be inserted in the destination.sh before  }

My exact code:
**Soure.sh**

```
xxx_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.xxx_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

xxx_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.xxx_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

xxx_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_xxx_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"
```

**Destination.sh**

```
{
    zzz_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.zzz_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    zzz_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.zzz_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

    zzz_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_zzz_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

    ccc_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ccc_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    ccc_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ccc_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"


    ccc_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_ccc_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

    rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr-ltf_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    rrr-ltf_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr-ltf_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

    rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_rrr-ltf_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"

    rrr_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

    rrr_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.rrr_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

    rrr_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_rrr_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"
    }
```

I need to insert the source.sh into the destination.sh before "}"

I have used

```
    { head -n -1 "$filenamelocalsource"; cat "$my_destination"; tail -n 1 "$filenamelocalsource"; } > tmp
mv tmp "$filenamelocaldestination"
```

**My output:**

```
ttt_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ttt_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"   
ttt_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.ttt_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"
continuum2_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_ttt_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"  
**}**   
mmm_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.mmm_ecmwf_main_state_machine.id}"

mmm_ecmwf_etl_state_machine_arn = "${aws_sfn_state_machine.mmm_ecmwf_etl_state_machine.id}"

mmm_ecmwf_scoring_function_name = "${aws_lambda_function.invoke_mmm_ecmwf_scoring_state_machine_lambda.function_name}"
```

I ran the command 
`{ echo "---------"; nl "$filenamelocal" | tail -2; echo "---------"; }`

[image]

Comment: Could you please post samples of both the files along with sample of expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13  i have attached the sample code. Could you please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$e cat file1' file2
```

Insert the file1 before the last line of file2.

Answer (score 0):

If the fileas are as you described, you can split the file to create a new one in three parts: beginning of file 2, file 2, end of file 1:

```
head -n -1 destination.sh > tmp
cat source.sh >> tmp
tail -n 1 destination.sh >> tmp
rm destination.sh
mv tmp destination.sh
```

The `tail -n 1 destination.sh >> tmp` can be substituted by `echo "}" >> tmp`, as long as it contains what you said.

All this code can be brought together to avoid opening the file for writing so many times. Also, the `mv` can overwrite the existing file, so we can avoid the `rm`:

```
{ head -n -1 destination.sh; cat source.sh; tail -n 1 destination.sh; } > tmp
mv tmp destination.sh
```

Comment: Last line of the destination file is }. I want to insert the contents before "}" in the destination file. But if i run the code as u suggested it is inserting the contents after the "}"

Comment: I have added the sample code also.Could you please help me on that!

Comment: Ops! I think I confused file1 and 2, you can just switch them, right?

Comment: @Poshi37 the content got inserted in the destination file...But } got removed...is there any way that without removing the contents can be inserted in the destination file

Comment: First: if "}" got removed, that's because you lied when you said it was the last line. Second: I already gave you a way to insert the "}" without reopening the input file.

Comment: I said } was the last line...but i want to insert the contents before }.
without removing

Comment: can u pls help me out in this!

Comment: The code provided do what you need. I already tested the code with your input samples and it generates your desired output. The `destination.sh` files is modified and the new contents are the ones that you asked for. Which is the issue you are having now?

Comment: @Poahi...It worked in the above sample..But in my original code it's not working...

Comment: Why? If you don't tell us what do you really have and need, there's no way we can help you.

Comment: I have attached the exact code...Could you pls help me

Comment: I created your files with the new information and reused the same code I posted as answer. It is working. Again: why you say it is not working on your side? What are you seeing? Which is the issue? There's something you didn't told us, or the files you posted are not exactly  the same as the files you have in your system. But without knowing what is happening, we can't help.

Comment: I have attched the sommand and the output...Contents are appending after "}" But i need to append the content before "}". I am not sure why it is appending "}". The attcahed snippet is the exact output i got.
Could you please help me

Comment: Are you completely sure that the last line of destination.sh is `}`? Run `{ echo "---------"; nl destination.sh | tail -2; echo "---------"; }` and post the result.

Comment: @Poshi..As suggested i ran the command and attached the output as picture. Pls help me

Comment: Good. Can you see for yourself that your last line is not the `}`?

Comment: Your `}` is not in the last, but the previous line. Change the number of lines you are cutting in the code I proposed from 1 to 2. That should solve your issue.

Comment: @Poshi...But for production ready, in tail I can't specify any hard coded number...Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Well, in your question you specified that the last line was `}`, and we asked multiple times if that was true, because our answers relied on that. If your reality is different and therefore your question, you should ask for whatever you really need. I can see another answer where `}` is used as the marker. Use that.

Comment: sorry, last line was not }. Can u help me in some other way other than tail command

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the changes to `destination.sh`:

```
printf "%s\n" '$-1r source.sh' w | ed -s destination.sh
```

This **r**eads the contents of `source.sh` into `destination.sh` before the last line of the file, and **w**rites it back out.

Comment: I have the command like "awk '/}/{system("cat "$my_file5"")} 1'  "$filenamelocal""  It didn't work. Contents are not inserting into the destination file

Comment: @clarie Don't use awk for something like this.

Comment: can u please help me out in this...how to insert the contents before } in a file

Comment: @clarie Er, see my answer? If the `}` in question isn't actually the last line like you said it was, use `/}/-1` instead of `$-1` for the address.

Comment: @shwan I ran the command printf "%s\n" '$-1r "$my_file5"' w | ed -s "$filenamelocal" .In the terminal I am getting output as ? when i go and see in the destination file, contents are not appended

Answer (score 0):

Using `ed(1)` and `printf`

```
printf '%s\n' '$-1r source.sh' ,p Q | ed -s destination.sh
```

That will just show you the output. To edit the file in-place use this.

```
printf '%s\n' '$-1r source.sh' w | ed -s destination.sh
```